# Openshift not setting environment variable for node project

Tags: node.js, openshift

I have a simple node project that I am trying to get deployed to Openshift Online 3 but having some ip and port problems.
Reading the [documentation](https://developers.openshift.com/languages/nodejs/environment-variables.html) I need to get some environment variables from openshift system, seems legit. But Openshift doesn't seem to set the variables OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT and OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP.

Using the example below:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server_ip_address = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || '127.0.0.1'
var port = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 1212

console.log('environment_port: ' + process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT);
console.log('environment_ip: ' + process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP);

app.listen(port, server_ip_address, function (err) {
    console.log('Running on port ' + port + ' ip: ' + server_ip_address);
});
```

I get the following output from openshift logs:

[image]

**Why isn't Openshift Online 3 setting the system varaibles?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In OpenShift 3, no environment variables will be set. Your HTTP server process should listen on port 8080 if using one of the S2I builders.

Comment: Hi, I'm facing the same problem on my migration :S Can you explain me a bit more? What about IP ? Thx!

Comment: Default to ``0.0.0.0`` instead of ``127.0.0.1``.

Comment: Thx! My app is now running with 0.0.0.0 with debug print "App listening on 0.0.0.0:8080" but still not available to the world, Am I missing something to expose my express.js end points? On version 2, everything was ok.

Mistery... now end points are live! Now my telegram bot is the only part with no connection...

Comment: How did you create the application, through the web console or on the command line? If you used the command line, a route to expose it via a URL to the public is NOT created and you need to create one yourself using ``os expose svc yourappname``.

Comment: I did it by web console, it now exposed (a bit slow...) -> http://granadabusnode6-granadabus.1d35.starter-us-east-1.openshiftapps.com/stops/

Next is expose my telegram bot... Do I need to open any kind of ports or similar? THX!!!

Comment: If your telegram bot is a backend service and only needs to be talked to by your front end, it should not be exposed by a route. Use the service name (likely same as app name), as a hostname when talking from frontend to backend. Note that if deploying from web console a route is automatically created, so if is a backend service that shouldn't be public, go into advanced options when creating app and disable the route creation.

Comment: My app does 2 things, first it's expose an API, and second has a telegram bot services running.